# What is void *reserved in the JNI_OnLoad function parameters?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

The signature of the JNI_OnLoad function is this:

`jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved);`

What is the void *reserved parameter?

Comment: It's a [pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/pointers) to an arbitrary block of memory.

Comment: And how do you decide what is the block of memory it points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the documentation doesn't explicitly say so, this parameter is reserved for future use and should be set to `NULL` in all cases.

Comment: Can you make an example of a future use of it?

Comment: That would match with `AttachCurrentThread`, but as you state, I'm not finding any explicit reference to this fact myself. I think that would be the gold standard for answering this question. @OP It's hard to make an example of a future use which hasn't been defined.

Comment: @na29 Maybe in a later version of Java you can pass a second parameter to `System.loadLibrary` which is the void* value

Comment: @na29 The next version of Java might decide to use that parameter for something.  By having that currently unused parameter, the interface won't need to change to add that functionality and therefore won't break backward compatibility.

Comment: So it is an unused parameter?

Comment: @na29 Yes, that's basically what "reserved" means.

Comment: @dbush and if you set it's value is it possible to access it outside of JNI_OnLoad?

Comment: Define "set its value". Note that you would be overwriting the value of a _local variable_, and it is not something that would carry across separate functions. C has many other means of achieving such.

Comment: @Rogue i mean if you make it point something later can you access it somehow?

Comment: @na29 If you set that parameter to a non-null value, you could cause a problem in later versions of Java that might use that parameter.

Comment: @dbush i know, but is that possible to access it later in another function

Comment: @na29 The parameter is currently unused.  That means that the function doesn't bother to read its value.

Comment: @na29 **no**. If you set the pointer, you would only change what the _local variable_ is pointing to. If you try to change the _value_ of the pointer, you will face a segmentation fault, since it is (most likely) a `NULL` pointer. If you want to share values across functions, you should look into using `struct` and potentially (albeit in a very reserved fashion) global variables.

Comment: @Rogue i am asking if there is a way to get a pointer that points to the same block outside of JNI_OnLoad

Comment: Yes, you need to create your own variable or pointer, more than likely using `malloc` to allocate the memory for the pointer, and then reference _that_. You will not be able to make `reserved` be the same value across function calls. You can control what the function does, not what it is called with.